# how to pass user input to oracle query in python

Tags: python, oracle

CODE

```python
cursor.execute("SELECT \* FROM employees WHERE email = :id", (10,))
```

ERROR

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

In Python, how to get data from the table as per given user input?

The email field is a string.

Answer (score 0):

The `email` column is not a number; however, you are trying to compare it to a number as your query is effectively being evaluated as:

```python
cursor.execute("SELECT \* FROM employees WHERE TO_NUMBER(email) = :id", (10,))
```

Which fails when the `email` column cannot be convert to a numeric value.

---

Either:

1. fix it in Python and pass a string:

   ```python
   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE email = :id", ("10",))
   ```

   or, if you are taking a value from somewhere else, explicitly convert it to a string:

   ```python
   email = 10  # although I am unclear why this would be a number and not a string.
   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE email = :id", (str(email),))
   ```

   or,
2. fix it in the database to ensure that `:id` is compared as a string:

   ```python
   cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE email = TO_CHAR(:id)", (10,))
   ```

*Note: It is probably better to get the right data-type in Python (option #1) than to pass something incorrect and working around the error in SQL (option #2).*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6mwMVbC6)

Comment: the date issue is not solved yet see my code 

import cx_Oracle
#------
def unlockhrs():
     start = datetime.date(2003-06-17)
     enddate = datetime.date(2003-06-17)

    conn = cx_Oracle.connect('hr/hr@10.0.0.77/xe')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #cursor.execute("""select * from employees where HIRE_DATE >= %s and date = %s """, (start, ))  # give error 

    cursor.execute("select * from employees where HIRE_DATE strftime('%Y-%m', Date) = ?", (start,))  # give error 
    rows = cursor.fetchall()    
    print(rows)
    conn.close()

Comment: cursor.execute("select * from employees where HIRE_DATE strftime('%Y-%m', Date) = ?", (start,))       #cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE HIRE_DATE = :start", (start,))    # give error 
    #cursor.execute("""select * from employees where HIRE_DATE >= %s and date = %s """, (start, ))  # give error 

    cursor.execute("select * from employees where HIRE_DATE strftime('%Y-%m', Date) = ?", (start,))  # give error

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code , please have a look

```
import cx_Oracle


user_input = input("Enter the email: ")

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@hostname/service_name')

cursor = connection.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE email = :email"
cursor.execute(query, email=user_input)

for row in cursor:
    print(row)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Dear Sir In a query, how do use the hardcode date 
query1 = """ SELECT * FROM employees WHERE HIRE_DATE = '2006, 9, 28'"""  
please guide me

Comment: query1 = """SELECT * FROM employees WHERE HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('2006-09-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD')"""

query1 = """SELECT * FROM employees WHERE HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('2006-09-28 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')"""

you can try any one which matches with your requirements